# Unable to view Product Page - Python django

Tags: python, django

Im new to python and django and working on a ecommerce project but facing some issues with product details page. Below are the codes for your reference. pls help out what im doing wrong here.

**Im trying to get product.product_name but its giving error no attribute**

view:

```
def product_page(request, myid):
print(myid)
product = Lat_Product.objects.filter(id=myid)
print(product)
return render(request, 'product_page.html', {'product': product})
```

url

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.lat_product, name="home"),
path('product_page/<int:myid>', views.product_page, name='product page')
]
```

model

```
class Lat_Product(models.Model):
objects = models.Manager()
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
product_price = models.IntegerField()
product_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
product_disc = models.BooleanField()
product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
product_new = models.BooleanField()
```

result

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
1
<QuerySet [<Lat_Product: Lat_Product object (1)>]>
[08/Jun/2020 17:21:37] "GET /product_page/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 17009
Not Found: /product_page/site.webmanifest
```

[08/Jun/2020 17:21:37] "GET /product_page/site.webmanifest HTTP/1.1" 404 3017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`product = Lat_Product.objects.filter(id=myid)`   You have to change this line to get attributes.

First option: `product = Lat_Product.objects.filter(id=myid).first()`

Second option: `product = Lat_Product.objects.get(id=myid)`